# Is there a good mechanism for making small images such as logos publicly available?

Tags: files, static-resources, images, document

I [read](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_create.htm&type=5) that "public" static resources are only accessible if already cached which probably explains sporadic results I've had:

> Public specifies that the static resource data cached on the Salesforce server is shared with other users in your organization for faster load times. After it’s cached, the resource is accessible to all Internet traffic, including unauthenticated users.

and though Documents with "Externally Available Image" checked still seem to work:

```
https://abc-def-1234-dev-ed.scratch.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer
    ?id=015xxxxxxxxxxxx&oid=00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

the lack of UI in Lightning for these is not encouraging.

For Asset Files that have "Let unauthenticated users see this asset file", there is the "Public Link" button that generates this pattern of URL:

```
https://abc-def-1234-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/xxxxxxxxxxxx/a
    /xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but seems sluggish and produces download UI by default.

What is the best way to expose a small image such as an icon so it is fully public i.e. always accessible from a "New Incognito Window"?

Comment: Publish it anywhere else outside of SF? It's an HTTP asset after all.

Comment: Hi @identigral sure. Just a pity if no easy way to do in SF.

Comment: the step up from Documents/Files is SF's CMS....which Dig Exp sites use for the very use case you're after. And no, you don't want to go there.

Comment: I use ContentAssets and have links to them in my HTML & VF emails  [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384022&type=1). I agree if you paste the link in the browser address bar it downloads, but they work as expected in guest Experience sites and emails

Comment: actually, in VF emails, the download link appears so I retract my previous comment

Comment: TIL -- some ContentAsset images in VF / HTML email render with download buttons, others do not - see https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/prevent-gmail-from-displaying-image-download-button-in-email/ - includes some workarounds